# How do I interpret 'detected downgrade...' NuGet error messages?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

I'm getting the followin error message i Visual Studio, from NuGet:

[image]

What I'm logically thinking is that first first package requires a version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting greater than or equal to 2.2.0, and the one below a version greater than or equal to 2.1.1.

So I already have version 2.2.0, yet it wants me to downgrade to 2.1.1 eventhough it satisfies the requirements (from my understanding).

Does the >= symbol mean something different?

Comment: What version of .net core does your project target? I think that usually revolves around your project's referenced version of .net core doesn't match with the minimum required by the package you are using

Comment: Looks like you update the version of Core on your machine.  The Visual Studio compiler is not very robust when it detects Net (or Core) version changes.  The version of the library is in the csproj file (which is text).  Often the version number in the csproj file is not updated properly giving these type errors.  I would first try to do a clean build.The may be obj files that didn't get updated after library was changed.If this doesn't work go to Solution Explorer and delete the reference to the library and then add which will put correct version in the csproj file.You could also edit csproj.

Comment: Thanks! This is the issue indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You interpreted it correctly - you can only resolve one package version and it seems like `2.2.0` would be the sensible version to pick as it satisfies both projects.

NuGet however uses a [nearest wins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins) resolution rule, so in your case picks `2.1.1`.

As it goes further down the transitive dependency chain it finds the other project, which requires `>=2.2.0`, but it's already resolved version `2.1.1`. So if it continued, this project that requested `>=2.2.0` would be getting `2.1.1` instead, so would be getting 'downgraded'.